# How to filter one spark dataframe against another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter one dataframe against another:

```
scala> val df1 = sc.parallelize((1 to 100).map(a=>(s"user $a", a*0.123, a))).toDF("name", "score", "user_id")
scala> val df2 = sc.parallelize(List(2,3,4,5,6)).toDF("valid_id")
```

Now I want to filter df1 and get back a dataframe that contains all the rows in df1 where user_id is in df2("valid_id"). In other words, I want all the rows in df1 where the user_id is either 2,3,4,5 or 6

```
scala> df1.select("user_id").filter($"user_id" in df2("valid_id"))
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) valid_id#20 missing from user_id#18 in operator !Filter user_id#18 IN (valid_id#20);
```

On the other hand when I try to do a filter against a function, everything looks great:

```
scala> df1.select("user_id").filter(($"user_id" % 2) === 0)
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [user_id: int]
```

Why am I getting this error? Is there something wrong with my syntax?

following comment I have tried to do a left outer join:

```
scala> df1.show
+-------+------------------+-------+
|   name|             score|user_id|
+-------+------------------+-------+
| user 1|             0.123|      1|
| user 2|             0.246|      2|
| user 3|             0.369|      3|
| user 4|             0.492|      4|
| user 5|             0.615|      5|
| user 6|             0.738|      6|
| user 7|             0.861|      7|
| user 8|             0.984|      8|
| user 9|             1.107|      9|
|user 10|              1.23|     10|
|user 11|             1.353|     11|
|user 12|             1.476|     12|
|user 13|             1.599|     13|
|user 14|             1.722|     14|
|user 15|             1.845|     15|
|user 16|             1.968|     16|
|user 17|             2.091|     17|
|user 18|             2.214|     18|
|user 19|2.3369999999999997|     19|
|user 20|              2.46|     20|
+-------+------------------+-------+
only showing top 20 rows

scala> df2.show
+--------+
|valid_id|
+--------+
|       2|
|       3|
|       4|
|       5|
|       6|
+--------+

scala> df1.join(df2, df1("user_id") === df2("valid_id"))
res6: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, score: double, user_id: int, valid_id: int]
scala> res6.collect
res7: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array()

scala> df1.join(df2, df1("user_id") === df2("valid_id"), "left_outer")
res8: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, score: double, user_id: int, valid_id: int]
scala> res8.count
res9: Long = 0
```

I'm running spark 1.5.0 with scala 2.10.5

Comment: You want to filter or perform a jointure over two Dataframes?

Comment: @eliasah I want to get a dataframe with a subset of the rows from df1. for each row r in df1, if the value of r("user_id") is in df2("valid_id"), then row r will be included in the result dataframe.

Comment: Then you'll have to perform a left outer join from df1 to df2 on userId == validId

Comment: @eliasah when I try, I get an empty dataframe, and it actually contains a union of all columns. I'll add an example to the question

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You want a (regular) inner join, not an outer join :)

```
df1.join(df2, df1("user_id") === df2("valid_id"))
```

Comment: Definitely! Sorry, my bad! Now I know that it's not a good idea to go on SO with insomnia :)

Comment: @glennie-helles-sindholt: Thanks for you answer. This make sense, but returns an empty dataframe. See my edits with code example in the question.

Comment: @polo I have to say that everything appears to be right, as far as I can see. I have just copied your commands to my own shell (also running Spark 1.5.0) and everything works perfectly. You do not by change have some explicit `val sc = new SparkContext(conf)` somewhere in your shell, do you? I recently stumbled across someone else who saw strange behaviour because he had declared the his own sc-variable. Otherwise, I think I'm fresh out of ideas as I simply cannot reproduce the problem. I assume you have tried to relaunch your shell?

Comment: @glennie-helles-sindholt: That's a great gotcha! I do actually have exactly that kind of sc. However, I want to keep it, since I want to define my own SparkConf (setting a spark.serializer). I also run my shell from my own project, with spark as an sbt dependency, rather than from the spark shell. Is it bad practice? Any advice?

Comment: @polo you should provide the the changes you have to the configuration as  parameters to spark-shell. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code in this way also 
join Types like **INNER, LEFT_OUTER, RIGHT_OUTER** etc

`df1.join(df2, col("user_id") === col("valid_id"), "${type_of_join}")`