# Out of memory issue when compare two large datasets using spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, hadoop2

I am daily importing 10 Million records from Mysql to Hive using Spark scala program and comparing datasets yesterdays and todays datasets.

```
val yesterdayDf=sqlContext.sql("select * from t_yesterdayProducts");
val todayDf=sqlContext.sql("select * from t_todayProducts");
val diffDf=todayDf.except(yesterdayDf);
```

I am using 3 node cluster and program working fine for 4 million records.
For more than 4 million we are facing out of memory issue as RAM memory is not sufficient.

I would like to know best way to compare two large datasets.

Comment: The dataframe has any kind of Unique key?

Comment: Yes  Thiago. Table has one unique key.

Comment: Actually, SparkSQL api call of except is an implicit call for substract  of spark api. If you have the key , can you try  todayDf.subtractByKey(yesterdayDf);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried findout out how many partitions do you have:
`yesterdayDf.rdd.partitions.size` will give you that information for yesterdayDf dataframe and you can do the same for other dataframes too.

You can also use
`yesterdayDf.repartition(1000) // (a large number)` to see if the OOM problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Tried this way
 `val yesterdayDf=sqlContext.sql("select * from t_yesterdayProducts");
yesterdayPartDf=yesterdayDf.repartition(1000)
val todayDf=sqlContext.sql("select * from t_todayProducts");
todayPartDf=todayDf.repartition(1000)
val diffDf=todayPartDf.except(yesterdayPartDf);`  
but after 993 tasks completed of first df throwing OOM problem

Comment: @ArvindKumarAnugula try 1200 or 1500 instead of 1000. Also specify --executor-memory 32G or higher

Comment: Exact memory issue is `GC memory overhead exceeded.`

Comment: Each node RAM size is 16GB only. can I use --executor-memory 16G ?

Comment: you can see config here what I am passing:

`--master yarn-client  --executor-memory 16G --num-executors 12 --executor-cores 4 --driver-memory 8G`

Comment: just a note: "--num-executors" has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is hard to say. But the issue could be that for some reason the workers are taking too many data. Try to clear the data frames to do the except. According to my question in comments, you said that you have key columns so take only they like this:

```
val yesterdayDfKey = yesterdayDf.select("key-column")
val todayDfKey = todayDf.select("key-column")
val diffDf=todayDfKey.except(yesterdayDfKey);
```

With that you will take an data frame with the keys. Than you can make a filter with that using join like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662632/how-to-filter-one-spark-dataframe-against-another-dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

you also need to make sure your yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb is larger than your --executor-memory.

Comment: This kind of suggestion should be kept in the comments

Answer (score 0):

you can also try joining two df on keys with left_anti join and then check count of number of records